# AngularJs File Upload in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

here is what I've tried till now

I cant send that file to my action result, its showing me null,

```
<form ng-show="divPatient" name="PatientForm" ng-submit="AddUpdatePatient()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly placeholder="Key (Automatic)" ng-model="PatientID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="FormFocus" name="FirstName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" ng-model="FirstName" ng-minlength="3" required />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="LastName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="LastName" ng-model="LastName" ng-minlength="3" required />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Disease" ng-model="Disease" name="Disease" ng-minlength="3" required />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Phone No." ng-model="PhoneNo" name="PhoneNo" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" required />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files)" accept="image/*" class="form-control" ng-model="PhotoURL" value="{{PhotoURL}}" required />
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="PatientForm.PhoneNo.$dirty && PatientForm.PhoneNo.$invalid || PatientForm.LastName.$dirty && PatientForm.LastName.$invalid || PatientForm.FirstName.$dirty && PatientForm.FirstName.$invalid || PatientForm.Disease.$dirty && PatientForm.Disease.$invalid" />
                        <input type="button" value="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="CancelForm()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.FirstName.$error.minlength">min 3 letters</span></td>
                    <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.LastName.$error.minlength">min 3 letters</span></td>
                    <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.Disease.$error.minlength">min 3 letters</span></td>
                    <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.PhoneNo.$error.pattern">Invalid phone no</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

$scope.selectFileforUpload = function (files) {
    $scope.selectedFile = files;
}

$scope.AddUpdatePatient = function () {
    var file = $scope.selectedFile[0];
    var Patient = {
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Disease: $scope.Disease,
        PhoneNo: $scope.PhoneNo
    };
    var getData = angularService.AddPatient(Patient,filee);
    getData.then(function (msg) {
        GetAllPatients();
        alert(msg.data);
        $scope.divPatient = false;
    }, function () {
        alert('Error in adding record');
    });
}
```

here is my service code

```
this.AddPatient = function (patient, file) {
    // this showing me file object thats fine
    alert("in services" + filee);
    // i think something wrong here we shouldn't or can't send the file to actionresult like this
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "AddPatient",
        data: JSON.stringify(patient),
        dataType: "json",
        // something wrong here ??
        file : file
    });
    return response;
}
```

amd last my method in my controller

```
public string AddPatient(Patient patient,HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
         // I'm getting patient data that is fine, but file is showing me null
}
```

is anything wrong with my service method ??? or do you know how to send form along with files to actionresult or any method in the mvc controller, i heard some pleople do it by using "new FormData", but i dont know that, but i'm willing to learn it or use it, if that solves my problem

Comment: Have a look at this : http://shazwazza.com/post/Uploading-files-and-JSON-data-in-the-same-request-with-Angular-JS

Comment: that did not help me, that is in web API